# php проверить существует ли файл

Tags: php, joomla

вот файл https://ci02236-joomla-amlwk.tw1.ru/Documents/Doc1.pdf - и он существует, как в php получить true если он есть или false если его не станет?
Пребывал несколько способов из поиска в google, и все они говорят, что файла не существует, хотя он есть! Помогите с решением.
среди тех, что пробовал:

```
 $urlHeaders = @get_headers($url);
 return stripos($urlHeaders[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
```

и вот это:

```
file_exists(string $filename): bool
```

а еще вот это:

```
// url файла для проверки на существование
$url = "http://site.com/image.jpg";
$urlHeaders = @get_headers($url);
// проверяем ответ сервера на наличие кода: 200 - ОК
if(strpos($urlHeaders[0], '200')) {
    echo "Файл существует";
} else {
    echo "Файл не найден";
}
```

и через if(@fopen($file, "r")) пробовал, но все говорят, что файла нет, хотя на какую-нибудь случайную картинку в поисковике работают нормально, в чем проблема ?

Comment: Скорее всего что-то не так с путем до файла.
Приведите какой пример с использованием file_exists, где он не работает?
И где расположен ваш скрипт где вы тестируете относительно корня сайта?

Comment: Пишу в материале joomla, пробовал разными способами, вдруг что получиться ?! хотелось бы через url

Comment: function find_file($filename)
{if(file_exists($filename)){echo "FILE YES";}else{echo "FILE NO";}}
find_file("Doc1.pdf"); //  просто файл
find_file("/Documents/Doc1.pdf"); // каталог в корне сайта
find_file("//Documents/Doc1.pdf"); // вариант 2, не знаю как правильней 
find_file("https://ci02236-joomla-amlwk.tw1.ru/Documents/Doc1.pdf"); //доступный url
find_file("/joomla_amlwk/public_html/Documents/Doc1.pdf"); //полный путь на хостинге
find_file("//joomla_amlwk/public_html/Documents/Doc1.pdf");  //полный путь на хостинге, вариант 2

Comment: find_file("/joomla_amlwk/public_html/Documents/Doc1.pdf") – вот этот вариант выглядит как рабочий.
Убедитесь с помощью \_\_DIR\_\_ , что полный путь правильный.

Comment: __DIR__ , а как ее использовать в данном случае ?

Comment: echo \_\_DIR\_\_;
в вашем php файле

Comment: в итоге получилось, что то подобное /home/c/*****/joomla_amlwk/public_html/public_html/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Используйте file_exists и полный путь до вашего файла на сервере.
Исходя из того, что вы написали в комментариях, то будет:

```
file_exists("/home/c/*****/joomla_amlwk/public_html/public_html/Documents/Doc1.pdf")
```

лучше конечно, используя __DIR__ 
если скрипт у вас находится в директории tmp, то

```
file_exists(__DIR__."/../Documents/Doc1.pdf")
```

Comment: Только получилось вот так вот:
file_exists("/home/c/*****/joomla_amlwk/public_html/Documents/Doc1.pdf")
а код из материала joomla получается располагаться еще в одной public_html внутри public_html в папке temp.
Большое спасибо за помощь! И хорошего вам дня!